# Trigger for update base on parent table condition

Tags: sql-server-2012

Hi I use SQL SERVER 2012 and I have two table named tbcustomer and tbcustomerdetail. Both tables have column customerID.

I manage only tbcustomerdetail.  If I update tbcustomerdetail where customerID='001' then I need the trigger to update tbcustomer where customerID='001'

I try this but not found spelling.

```
       CREATE TRIGGER Deletecustomer
       ON tbcustomerdetail
       FOR UPDATE
       AS
       BEGIN

            update tbcustomer tbcustomer.status=0 where     tbcustomer.customerID=updated.customerID;

       END

      //updated.customerID is the ID on column tbcustomerdetail where customerID is '001'.
```

I also tried AFTER UPDATE but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Updated` does not exist, in a trigger you have two views `Deleted` which contains previous data and `Inserted` contains the new one

As I mentioned they are views, and contains data for all the rows affected by the statement, so, you need to use them in a join

```
CREATE TRIGGER Deletecustomer
ON tbcustomerdetail
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE C 
        SET Status = 0
    FROM tbCustomer C
    JOIN Inserted I ON C.CustomerID = I.CustomerID
END
```